# when looking up an EJB component in a remote GlassFish I got a local instead

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi, glassfish-4

I have a problem with JNDI lookup for remote interface
There is 2 servers:
- first main server;
- second slave server (it will be more than one, but now just one);
The main server should connect to the slave to update metadata, but when it looked up a remote interface it got a local one (both servers has same interfaces).

declaration of interface

```
@Remote
public interface IMetadataRemote {
```

implementation

```
@Remote(IMetadataRemote.class)
@Stateless(mappedName = "MetadataSync")
public class MetadataRemoteImpl implements IMetadataRemote {
```

look up code:

```
    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();

    jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
    jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

    jndiProps.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", serviceIp);
    jndiProps.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", servicePort);

    Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    IMetadataRemote metadataRemote = (IMetadataRemote) ctx.lookup("MetadataSync");
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Are you using the correct `host` and `port`? ie: `serviceIp` and `servicePort`.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.
If it had been incorrect, I would caught the exception.